# Program received signal:EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What to do with this?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I just recently started learning Objective C/Cocoa and I know how important the memory management is and I believe this error I've been having is regarding to that.

I have a very very simple screen: two UITextView, one Button, one UILabel.

My header file has:

```
@interface PontaiViewController : UIViewController {

UITextField *loginField;
UITextField *passwordField;
UILabel *userID;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *loginField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *userID;


- (IBAction) btnLoginClicked:(id) sender;
```

The implementation has:

```
@implementation PontaiViewController
@synthesize loginField;
@synthesize passwordField;
@synthesize userID;
-(IBAction) btnLoginClicked:(id)sender {
NSString *string1 = @"username=";
NSString *string2 = [string1 stringByAppendingString:(loginField.text)];
NSString *string3 = [string2 stringByAppendingString:(@"&password=")];
NSString *post = [string3 stringByAppendingString:(passwordField.text)];
NSLog(@"The post is %@", post);
userID.text=loginField.text;
[string1 release];
[string2 release];
[string3 release];
[post release];
```

}

and it finishes with

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.loginField=nil;
    self.passwordField=nil;
    self.userID=nil;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [loginField release];
    [passwordField release];
    [userID release];
}
```

When I run this demo, and try to write something in the TextView, I get this error.

What could it be?

Regards,
Felipe

Comment: Where exactly is the error happening?  On `userID.text=loginField.text;`?  If so, are you sure you connected the `userID` field to something in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3):

Also, your NSStrings are autoreleased, and then you're releasing them again (over releasing).  Read up on memory management of convenience methods.

Comment: Also try: `NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormattedString:@"username=%@&password=%@", loginField.text, passwordField.text];`  And don't release post with this example either.

Comment: Additionally `[super dealloc];` should go last.

Answer (score 2):

In `viewDidUnload` you set `loginField` to `nil`, then you try to release it in `dealloc`. This isn't right. You only need to release valid items that you own.

Additionally, (as pointed out in a comment) you need to put `[super dealloc]` at the end of the `dealloc` function.

As pointed out by others, you also should not release the strings you're getting from `stringByAppendingString`.

Here are some basic rules about how to manage memory in Objective-C under iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html

One thing you will find is that you only release stuff you are responsible for, and you're not responsible for it unless it was created with one of these:

alloc, allocWithZone:, copy, copyWithZone:, mutableCopy, mutableCopyWithZone

Comment: I see
I thought I was responsible for objects I created with the 'retain' keywoard as well.
Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Sure! Memory management in Obj-C is very different from normal C / C++, and can be tricky to learn at first.

Answer (score 2):

`stringByAppendingString` returns an autoreleased object, don't release `string1`, `string2`, `string3` and `post`.

Answer (score 1):

You should comment out the following

```
//[string1 release];
//[string2 release];
//[string3 release];
//[post release];
```

since you are using helper methods and not explicitly allocating anything.